# Sqlalchemy hybrid_property how to pass parameters during query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I have sqlalchemy model which represents a 'post' a user has made

```
class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    caption = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("instagram_user.id"))

    user = relationship("User")
    likes = relationship("Like")
```

I want to be able to know if the post has been liked by a user so I add a `hybrid_method`:

```
@hybrid_method
def is_liked_by(self, user):
    return any(like.user_id == user.id for like in self.likes)
```

I can now get if a post has been liked by a specific user which is fine:

```
post = db.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id == user.id).one()
post.is_liked_by(user) # True / False
```

However, I would like the `is_liked_by` to be stored as an attribute property on the orm object as so:

```
@hybrid_property
def has_liked(self, user)
    return any(like.user_id == user.id for like in self.likes)
```

So then I can do something like this:

```
post = db.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id == user.id)
         .bindparams({'user': user}) # this gets passed to the hybrid property above
         .one()

post.has_liked # True / False
```

The context of wanting to do this is so I can easily convert to a pydantic model including all the hybrid fields

```
class PostRead(BaseModel):
    id: int
    caption: str
    user: UserRead
    has_liked: bool


pydantic_post = PostRead.from_orm(post)
pydantic_post.has_liked # True / False
```

So is there any way to replicate the functionality shown above in sqlalchemy? I basically want to pass through some context when making the query for a post, in this case being the viewing user so I can get whether they have liked the post or not.